# Can i access C# method through fully quantified name without specifying it in "using: section?

Tags: c#

So here's the question. There is some functionality that allows to insert some c# code. But i can' get it work because some classes are not specified in "using" section eve though i am using full class name.

Comment: We can't tell what's wrong without seeing your code... please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Yes you can use it ... the only thing important is that you need to make the reference of the dll for using it

Comment: Can we see the code/class? It could be anything from a misspelling to a missing framework to something in your compiled application.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are referencing them in your project. 
Some .dll files are not included as standard.
Example when writing a class library project you need to include System.Web to access it.